# User Permissions Not Updating

Tags: joomla

Let me start with I have read numerous posts regarding this issue and have tried the max_input_vars = 2500 and I only have 10 groups (nine standard and one added).

I am trying to add the View My Invoices for all Registered users. So selecting that option and changing the permissions to Allow for Registered shows the new setting to be correct but when you hit save/save and close it doesn't actually update. I do get the updates saved message, but again no update.

I have gone into the database and manually added this code {"2":1},"civicrm.view_my_invoices": in the Asset table. That will display the Print Invoice button in the users Dashboard, however, when you click it you get a Joomla error page that indicates that you don't have permissions to access this page.

I am hoping someone has suggestions or possibly post their Asset table civicrm Rules entry that is working on their site. Thanks for any suggestions or advice.

Comment: What versions are you running?

Comment: I am using Joomla 3.5.1 and Civicrm 4.7.7. I have 20+ entries in my assets table for civi, but had to manually add the view_my_invoices function due to the permissions not saving. The Print Invoice works for Superusers, but not for Registered.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am having the issue on at least 2 sites, J 3.5.1 and both Civi 4.6.16 and 4.7.7. I had to update the json in the assets table manually to make the permission stick. Make sure that you are also quoting the 1. ex. {"2":"1"}, as opposed to {"2",1}

Answer (score 1):

Working. New install. Using J!v 3.5.1/CiviCRM 4.7.7. db-prefix_assets/row name = com_civicrm; rules={"1":1,"2":1},"civicrm.view_event_info":{"1":1,"2":1},"civicrm.view_event_participants":{"1":1,"2":1}}